# onload focus causes div to get cut off

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a DIV for my menu, and a DIV for my textbox area and label.

```
<div id="divMenuParent" name="divMenuParent"
        style="padding-top: 20px; z-index: 9; border: solid 5px gray; 
            position:absolute; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 75px;
            z-index: 9999; left: 500px; background-color:#CCFFFB;
            height: 50px; width:100px; font-size: 1.5em; text-align: center;">
    MENU
</div>




<div id="divInput" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 20px; z-index: 1;">
    <label style="font-size:1.5em; width:450px;">Please enter a SKU or UPC</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="txtSKUUPC" name="txtSKUUPC"
            style="height:100px;
                 width:600px;
                 font-size: 1.5em;
                 border: solid 2px gray;" />
                
</div>
```

It looks great when i dont automatically set the focus, but when i do this code just below, it cuts off the bottom half of my menu.  The moment i comment the focus line out again, it looks fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById('txtSKUUPC').focus();
    });
</script>
```

When the error happens, I'm using Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic with the default Internet Explorer.  When viewing this page on any other browser from my XP box it works just fine.

My initial thought was that the label / textbox were cutting off the bottom of the menu.. but they are absolutely positioned, and i can move them another 400 pixels down and it still happens.

[image]

Comment: While not the solution to this particular problem, would using HTML5's `autofocus` property be a better solution? I might remove this bizarre error.

Comment: That was the solution! post it as an answer and i'll accept it ;)  Thank you for the suggestion!!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't feel right having you accept that answer, since that isn't the real problem at hand. I'm more interested to know if anyone knows a fix to this specific quirk. I'm glad it worked though :)